# Problem with Visual Studio 2010 DataTips in a mixed C++/CLI assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, debugging, tooltip

I've recently switched to using Visual Studio 2010. I've got a problem where the DataTips (debugger tooltips) for STL types aren't loading correctly.

For example, in the following code:

```
int test( const std::string& inString )
{
    std::string aString( "Hello, World!" );

    return aString.compare( inString );
}
```

I don't get the expected tooltip (**[+] aString| "Hello, World!"**) but instead get something like **[+] aString | {npos=4294967295}**.

Ex.
[image]
<sub>(source: [bordeaugrove.com](http://bordeaugrove.com/wrong.png))</sub>

I've tested things a little and I've found that in my native (unmanaged) Projects, I don't get the problem. The Project where I'm getting this problem is a mixed native and C++/CLI DLL.

I'm aware the Intellisense isn't supported for C++/CLI in Visual Studio 2010, but as far as I know, this should be working in the debugger.

I'm wondering if I've just got a corrupt installation or the incorrect settings somewhere.

Anybody got any suggestions?

Comment: Is this in an optimized build?  I've seen the same sort of issue, where the display of Standard Library containers such as `std::vector` was totally wrong, in release builds of native code.  Debug (optimization disabled) builds are always fine.  I think the visualizer assumes a particular layout or uses some field that is conditionally defined and exists only in debug builds.

Answer (score 0):

According to the first couple of comments [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/27/rebuilding-intellisense.aspx), C++/CLI isn't supported by VS2010 intellisense.  The second comment is by a member of the MS team and he offers a rationalization for this.

Comment: debugger insight isn't *intellisense*

Answer (score 0):

According to ["std-string-content-not-shown-in-the-debugger"](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/614901/std-string-content-not-shown-in-the-debugger) this is caused by mixing libraries built with VS 2005 and VS 2010. However there may be multiple causes.

One potential workaround is to add the following to your watch window, where `message` is a `std::string`

```
message._Bx._Ptr // use when the string is longer than 16 characters
message._Bx._Buf // use when the string is less than or equal to 16 characters
```

These variables can be found either by browsing the STL source, or by using the following in the watch window to expand the object, where `message` is a `std::string` it allows browsing the objects raw format, ignoring any data type views customizations:

```
message,!
```

A more in depth explanation of this and other watch window format specifiers can be found at [Format Specifiers in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt(v=vs.100).aspx).